# Can't change the height of uitoolbar with objective c

Tags: objective-c, uitoolbar

I have successfully added a UIToolBar with the following code:

```
-(void) setUpBottom{

    UIBarButtonItem *flexible = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithBarButtonSystemItem:UIBarButtonSystemItemFlexibleSpace target:self action:nil];
    UIBarButtonItem *feature = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"features.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(selectFeature:)];

    UIBarButtonItem *fav = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc]initWithImage:[UIImage imageNamed:@"favorite-outline.png"] style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(selectFavorite:)];

    //following line was intended to change the height of the tool bar, but it doesn't work.
    [[self navigationController].toolbar setFrame:CGRectMake(0, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.height - 55, [[UIScreen mainScreen] bounds].size.width, 55)];

    self.toolbarItems = [NSArray arrayWithObjects:flexible,feature, flexible,fav,flexible,nil];
    [[self navigationController] setToolbarHidden:NO];
}
```

The thing wonders me is that:

- when I assign the toolBarItems to `[self navigationController].toolbarItems` the item will not show up
- There is no API that I can find to modify the toolbar's height so I have to modify the one on `[self navigationController]` which not work

So my question is how can I modify the height of the boolbar, and more over, what's the relation of `self.toolbarItems` and `[self navigationController].toolbarItems` ? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

ToolbarItems property of a UINavigationController has no effect on its own toolbar.

```
NS_CLASS_AVAILABLE_IOS(2_0) @interface UINavigationController : UIViewController
```

You should note that it is inherited from UIViewController and only effective if you put that navigation controller inside another navigation controller.

to increase Height of i think you can't subclass it and  change intrinsicContentSize  or sizeThatFits

you can create UIView and ad as subview

Comment: You mean I should create a UIView and put that subview in the bottom as the tab instead of the using Toolbar right?

Comment: Yes you can make another solution

Answer (score 0):

According to [documentation](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uinavigationcontroller/1621882-toolbar#discussion):

you can assign a custom set of toolbar items using the [**setToolbarItems:animated:**](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiviewcontroller/1621874-settoolbaritems?language=objc) method of **UIViewController**

But I'm not sure if you can change the height of the build-in toolbar